# Find stopping time of train given the speed with and without stopping

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

> Without stopping for passengers, a train travels a certain distance with an average speed of 60 km/h, and when it stops, it covers the same distance with an average speed of 40 km/h. On average, how many minutes per hour does the train stop during the journey?

My approach: average speed = total distance/ total time;

Here it is given that the first train's speed is $60$ km/h.

$\therefore 60 = \frac{x}{t_1}$ where $x$ is the total distance and $t_1$ is total time.

Now average speed is 40 km/hr.

$\therefore 40 = \frac{x}{t_2}$ where $x$ is the total distance and $t_2$ is total time.

Now solving this I get $3t_1= 2t_2$ but I don't understand how to approach the solution from here.

Comment: Is there any more to the problem?

Comment: FWIW I had trouble understanding the problem: what does "how many minutes does it stop for" mean? Normally trains can't instantly go from 60km/h to 0, or get back to 60 instantly either. So some of the reduced average speed is due to slowing down (which one might call "stopping"), some to waiting aounrd (which one might call "stopping"), and some to speeding up. I only figured out the intended answer because we don't have enough data to answer any of the other possible interpretations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $3t_1 = 2t_2$, we get $t_1 = \frac{2}{3}t_2$. This means that two-thirds of the time, the train is running, so during the other one-third of the time, the train is stopping.

This means the train stops for $\frac{1}{3} \times 60 = 20$ minutes every hour.

It might help to let the distance be a number, as the proportions will remain unchanged (minutes *per* hour). For example, if the distance is $120 \text{km}$, then the train runs for $2$ hours without stopping, and $3$ hours with stopping. Hence $1$ hour out of every $3$ hours is spent stopping, which is the same as $20$ minutes every $1$ hour.

Comment: Thanks your answer cleared the concept :)

Comment: The solution is immediate if you keep everything "per hour": 40 km is 40 minutes of travelling.

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 3):

Travelling 40 km takes 40 min, hence 20 min of standstill per hour.

(In fact, the train travelled for an hour and waited 30 minutes.)

---

For an algebraic solution (though this seems overkill), let $t$ the stopping time *per $60$ minutes*, we have

$${40\text{ km/h}}\times{60\text{ min}}={60\text{ km/h}}\times{(60-t)\text{ min}}.$$

Answer (score 3):

We have that

$$60=\frac d {t}\, (km/h), \quad 40=\frac d {t+t_0}\, (km/h)$$

then

$$60 t=40(t+t_0) \implies 20 t=40 t_0  \implies \frac{t}{t_0}=2$$

and then

$$\frac{t_0}{t+t_0}=\frac1{\frac t {t_0}+1}=\frac1 3$$

that is 20 minutes per hour.

---

By your way from here $$3t_1= 2t_2 \iff t_1=\frac23 t_2 =\frac23 (t_1+t_0) \iff t_1=2 t_0$$ which leads to the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Now I also understand we can also think like this :)

Comment: @SanjayVerma This is an algebric solution which is important as for the intuition with direct check assuming a fixed time for the travel. It confirms the intuition.